# TDictionary, como destruí-lo

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

Já tentei de todas as formas destruir `TDictionary` mas sempre que tenho o `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` ativo ele deixa sempre algo sem ser destruído. 
Já tentei correr a lista e destruir item a item.

Código:

```
with foDict.GetEnumerator do
  while MoveNext do
    Current.Value.Free;

foDict.Free;
```

Como tentei também destruir somente o `foDict.Free;`

Ambas há vazamento de memória. Alguém ai tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: é só este o seu código onde utiliza o foDict? @ElanDuarteFraga

Comment: problema é só para dar um free nele. foDict: TDictionary<integer, TCliente>; Funciona perfeitamente mas ao liberar ele da memória sempre fica algum "lixo".

Comment: tentou minha resposta? @ElanDuarteFraga

Comment: Não vi como testar sua resposta mas criei o projeto para explicar melhor https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77323830/TDictionary.rar

Comment: Quando você cria um Dicionário, a melhor forma de garantir que ele vai ser liberado, é utilizar o parâmetro doOwnsValue no create: `myDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Create([doOwnsValues])`

Comment: E ai @ElanDuarteFraga , algum avanço ?

Comment: @ElanDuarteFraga se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise

Answer (score 2):

Usando o seu exemplo, o código teria as seguintes alterações:

**Nova classe:**

```
TMyCustomDictionary = TObjectDictionary<integer, TCliente>;
```

**Nova utilização do objeto foDict:**

```
foDict: TMyCustomDictionary;
```

**Novo create do objeto foDict**

```
foDict := TMyCustomDictionary.Create([doOwnsValues]);
```

Feito isso, o botão `FreeList`, passa a não ter mais utidade

Answer (score 0):

Testa da seguinte forma::

```
destructor TMemCorrectedDictionary.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  Values.Free;
  Keys.Free;
end;
```

> Mais informações aqui: [Memory Leak in TDictionary - Problems with Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511289/memory-leak-in-tdictionary-problems-with-workaround)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, with TObjectDictionary you can use .Create([doOwnsValues]) that free all objects automatically.
[doOwnsValues] is not possible to TDictionary, you need to do manually.